# How to test Semi-Autonomous app mode in iOS simulator or on a dev device

Tags: ios, mdm

When using the call

UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession

To put an app in and out of single app mode, as far as I know this only works on a device in MDM that is supervised. I am wondering if there is a convenient way to test this during development?

If possible I would love to do this in the simulator, however I do have a device that is in our MDM and is supervised. However I am unsure how to test it on the device, I can't specify the app in the MDM provider's list of apps since its not in the app store yet. What am I missing?

Note, we do not have an enterprise development account, we have less than 100 employees. I don't need to deploy the app through MDM, I can deploy it through the apple store, but don't want to go through the store for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found any documentation or answers for this, but I did end up working through it.

Here is what I ended up doing.

Get the app on the app store, not just as a beta. I had to implement as much as I could to make the app functional enough to get published on the app store.

Deploy MDM policies with the new app. If you aren't on the app store, at least in the MDM tools I used I couldn't set the policy, hence the need to get it on the app store.

Now you can install app onto device with MDM policies (via testflight beta only) and test.

It would be nice if you could put a simulator in a mode where it accepts UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession.